# problem with .bag file

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've recorded, using rosbag, a .bag file with images from a gscam node and message from the gmapping-slam node and I'd like to create a file that associate each image to the corresponding estimated pose. I think I can to this with rxbag, but I can't extract timestamps of images to relate them with the poses and I've also some problem in converting the poses data from the .bag file to another file, like CSV, to use that in some other environment. Do you have some suggestion?
Thanks for helping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11598/problem-with-.bag-file/) by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-16**:
This sounds like your camera driver was not filling in the timestamps correctly.  I suggest you file a ticket for the camera node you are using.

**Comment by [Antonio](https://answers.ros.org/users/311/antonio/) on 2011-10-20**:
with rxbag I select view(Topic)->gscam/img-raw->raw and when I analyze the header, in the field stamp I got always the zero value? Maybe there's a problem with the camera topic, or something else, or am I doing something wrong?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-19**:
The images should have timestamps. Are you sure they do not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably write tools to do some of this yourself with the [ROSbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2